# How do I Install the Crunch app for Adobe Air?

Tags: air, installation, less

I never used anything Air but Adobe Muse and Adobe Edge, and they both have installer packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running Windows 7 and I followed these steps below.

- Download crunchapp from http://crunchapp.net/ and extract to any location
- Install Adobe Air SDK by going to their site.
- Unzip it to appropriate folder (*I extracted to C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe AIR SDK*)
- Right-click on "My Computer" in the Start menu and select Properties.
- Click on "Advanced System Settings" on the left hand side menu
- Select "Environment Variables" and add two new system variables as below

> adl
>   [change path to your extracted Adobe AIR SDK\bin\adl.exe file]

(*I used - C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe AIR SDK\bin\adl.exe* )

> adt
>    [change path to your extracted Adobe AIR SDK\bin\adt.bat file]

(*I used -  C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe AIR SDK\bin\adt.bat* )

- RESTART PC (*this caught me out*)
- Open command Line Interface and navigation to C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe AIR SDK\bin\
- type in adl [full path to Crunch folder]application.xml
- Enjoy Crunch!!!!

HTH

Ralph

Answer (score 0):

In my Windows machine, this is what I did just now (because, I also did not know where to start):

- You need to download the Adobe Air SDK
- Extract its content and I followed this: http://chisflorinel.blogspot.com/2007/06/installing-adobe-air-on-windows-vista.html

After that, I opened my command line, then went to the Crunch! folder, then type the command:

```
adl application.xml
```